# Angular Template Cache - Clear Cache For Updated Template

Tags: angularjs, templates, caching

I have an Angular that uses templates via directives.  With one of the templates I have there was a bug.  After making the change and refreshing my browser I noticed it was not using the file I fixed the bug in.  I then learned about template caching.  Great feature, but how do I clear out the cache for this updated template?

Note: I'm not using Angular's routes.  Just accessing templates via a directive.

Answer (score 0):

Did You use gulp or Grunt?

I personally use template-cache, what it does it collects all html partials/templates and put them into on js file.

pros: 
* all templates are loaded at once in one js file.

cons:
* each time You change your html files You have to regenerate your template-cache. You could use gulp to watch your html files and each time You change something it automatically regenerate template-cache for You :)

to sum up, get interesting with `gulp-watch` and `gulp-angular-templatecache` to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll look into this.  For now what I'm doing is adding a suffix with a random number at the end of the templateURL (e.g.'template.html?123').  This may be a hack, but to keep me going it works.

Answer (score 0):

As an extension of appending your template urls with a number, you might consider instead intercepting the request (all of them) and appending a number (version, release, date, etc) there. Something like this:

```
angular.module('my-app', []).config(function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($window) {
    return {
      'request': function(config) {
        // just yours (other libs, ie pagination might conflict with
        // their own insertions)
        if (!/^\/path-to-your-templates\//.test(config.url)) {
          return config;
        }
        // pull a # from wherever you like, maybe the window - set by
        // your backend layout engine?
        if ($window.version) {
          if (!config.params) {
            config.params = {};
          }
          if (!config.params.v) {
            config.params.v = $window.version;
          }
        }
        return config;
      }
    };
  });
});
```